# Any software to help manage mass combat from Ultimate Campaign?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, tools, mass-combat

I'm new to Pathfinder (haven't event looked at RPGs since AD&D 2e) and I've been investigating the concept of mass combat for a campaign I'm thinking about creating.

I guess Ultimate Campaign is a bit new(?), but has anyone used any software tools to help manage this new ruleset?  Do they work?

Comment: It's okay to be Pathfinder-specific! There's no need to artificially broaden your question; and besides, 4e is entirely incompatible with every other edition of D&D and 3.5 doesn't have a similar mass combat system, so software aimed at them wouldn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is support for it (and all the other stuff in Ultimate Campaign) in [Hero Lab](http://www.wolflair.com/index.php?context=hero_lab).  See [this Wolf Lair forum post](http://forums.wolflair.com/showpost.php?p=158969&postcount=2) for what and where it is in the program.

Hero Lab is expensive, but running Pathfinder without it is like stabbing yourself in the leg repeatedly. It makes NPC creation and management, and applying status and stuff in combat, so nice.

Answer (score 2):

[Battle Chronicler](http://battlechronicler.com/) is not really a battle auto-development software, but it can be used for a global view of the battlefield. You can give it a try.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, please take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour)!

Answer (score 1):

Look for a set of Wargames rules called "Hordes of the Things" - HotT for short, By WRG. Concepts are good, but the grammar the author uses leads something to be desired (the UK wargaming community calls it "Barker-ease" because its not English)

Comment: OP was looking for software to help with the Ultimate Campaign combat rules - does this recommendation actually meet that need?

Answer (score -1):

You could always use a spreadsheet or make a pack of note cards with names of the characters on them, recording notes as you go along through the pack in order.

Comment: While a good suggestion, this doesn't actually answer the question because OP is specifically asking for software. If you included more information about why note cards or a simple database is *better* than available software, this could be a great answer that [challenges the frame](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3318/how-do-we-handle-a-desire-to-challenge-the-frame-of-a-question) of the question.